# How to query get collections like in pymongo (javascript)

Tags: python, pymongo

From Mongo console I can use Javascript to get collections like,by using the following function

`db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(d){if(d.match(/_test$/)){print (d);}})`
which gives all collections whose name end with test.

How can I do the same via python i.e pymongo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [collection_names](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.collection_names):

```
import pymongo
c = pymongo.MongoClient()
for nm in c.my_database.collection_names():
    if nm.endswith('test'):
        print(nm)
```

Replace "my_database" with the name of the database whose collections you want to list.